# Access service variables In Subscribe as Component Variables Angular7/NGRX

Tags: angular, service, components, ngrx, angular7

I have a Component that is importing a service. The Component calls a method on the class of the service. Inside this method are variables that get assigned/augmented. I want those to be tied to the component variables.  The subscribe is working as intended. How do you do this? Is the only way to do this by using something like this:

```js
@Output() change: EventEmitter < boolean > = new EventEmitter();

toggle() {
  this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  this.change.emit(this.isOpen);
}
```

and than subscribe to that in the component.

`Component.ts` - abbreviated example.

```js
import { GridBuilderService } from '../../shared/services/grid.service';

export class MeetingStatusReportComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  communicationService,
  criteria: blahahah;
  resizeGrid: blahahah;
  gridOptions: blahahah;
  loadingDisable: blahahah;
  totalRecords: blahahah;

  constructor(
    public gridBuilder: GridBuilderService
  ) {}

  ...

  this.gridBuilder.subscribeForChanges(
    this.communicationService,
    this.criteria,
    this.resizeGrid,
    this.gridOptions,
    this.loadingDisable,
    this.totalRecords,
    params
  );
}
```

`gridService.ts` - abbreviated example

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GridBuilderService {

  subscribeForChanges(
    communicationService, 
    criteria, 
    resizeGrid, 
    gridOptions, 
    loadingDisable, 
    totalRecords, 
    params
  ) {
    return communicationService.getMeetingStatusReportData(criteria)
    .subscribe(result => {
      let lastRow = result.meetings.totalRecords;
      resizeGrid();
      gridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
      loadingDisable = false; // want to set the this.loadingDisable on the component or carry it over somehow to assign.
      if (result.meetings.totalRecords === 0) {
        this.gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
      }
      totalRecords = lastRow;
      // call the success callback
      params.successCallback(result.meetings.results, lastRow);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it to work by using the subscribe event as noted - got it from here at the bottom of the page - https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb but is there a better way?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is access the value of `loadingDisable`, then why not simply store it as a class-scope variable in GridBuilderService?  Then from within your component you can just access it with `gridBuilder.loadingDisable`